# Transloadit cannot get ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED response in c#.net

Tags: c#, transloadit

With the reference from below link

https://github.com/nkranitz/transloadit-csharp-sdk
Am using transloadit for video converting and saving it in s3 in C#. I am able to upload the video and image and am able to get the response with empty results. My response had "ok": "ASSEMBLY_EXECUTING", message and the results tag is empty. So am not getting the final response once the assembly is executed like ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED. So, i see that there is some property assembly.setblocking = true.. but in C# that property is not available. So how can i get the final response or how can i use blocking property in c#.net

Please help me out in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the code snippet

ITransloadit transloadit = new Transloadit.Transloadit("APIKEY", "Secret");

```
        //Create assembly builder to build up the assembly
        IAssemblyBuilder assembly = new AssemblyBuilder();
        //Add a file to be uploaded (with autogenerated key)
        assembly.AddFile(@"filepath"); 

       //Define the step, you can define more in the same assembly
        IStep step = new Step();
        step.SetOption("robot", "/image/resize");
        step.SetOption("width", 75);
        step.SetOption("height", 75);
        step.SetOption("resize_strategy", "pad");
        step.SetOption("background", "#000000");

        //Add the step to the assembly
        assembly.AddStep("thumb", step);

        //Set notification URL
        assembly.SetNotifyURL("url");

        //Set the expiration date time of the request for the assembly
        //Assembly will be expired in 120 minutes from now
        assembly.SetAuthExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120));
        //Invoke assembly, and wait for the result
        TransloaditResponse response = transloadit.InvokeAssembly(assembly);

        if (response.Success)
        {
          //  LoggerFactory.GetLogger().LogInfo(Type.GetType("TestConsole.Program"), "Assembly {0} result", response.Data);
        }
```

Comment: Why is this tagged 'java'.  It seems to be solely a C# question.

Comment: Hi Stephen, as i see that in android that setblocking property is available and as it is in java, i tagged it with java too.

Comment: The java tag is irrelevant.  Your question doesn't even mention Android.  But even it it did, the question is not **about** android specifically or java more generally.  I have removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that first response, you should see an `assembly_url`. You can/should poll that URL every *X* seconds to get the updates. When the assembly reaches `ASSEMBLY_CANCELED` `ASSEMBLY_COMPLETED` `REQUEST_ABORTED`, or the `error` is set, it's done. I'm not sure if the boilerplate for this polling is implemented in the SDK, you'd have to check.

Blocking assemblies are not recommended as they require to keep the connection open, which is more brittle.